# Trying to open a file, wrong format?

Tags: c#

Im trying to open a file. Here is my output (string i build up in try/catch):

Error opening c:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\storedUsers.txt -> System.FormatException -> Input string was not in a correct format.

And here is how im opening it:

```
installPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\";
FileStream userFile = new FileStream(installPath + "storedUsers.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader userStream = new StreamReader(userFile);
while (userStream.Peek() >= 0)
{
string line = userStream.ReadLine();
storedUsers.Add(line.Split(',')[0], int.Parse(line.Split(',')[0]));
}
userStream.Close();
```

My catch:

```
WriteToLogFile("Error opening " + installPath + "storedUsers.txt -> " + ex.GetType() + " -> " + ex.Message);
```

I cant wrap my head around whats wrong...

Comment: On which line is it throwing the exception?

Comment: Are you sure the path for the file is properly formed? 



c:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\storedUsers.txt



does not seem so correct.

Comment: `FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);` <- hhm, this is counter intuitive. If you potentially create a file, you would use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);` - otherwise, why should you create it, if you don't want to write to it? or `FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` if you want to read from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess here, since you haven't given us enough to really give you a solid answer.

I bet the problem is the parsing of that line part, this expression:

```
int.Parse(line.Split(',')[0])
```

That this doesn't, in all cases, actually give you a number.

So you should look at the file, and possibly change the code to this:

```
string[] parts = line.Split(',');
... int.Parse(parts[0]) ...
```

Then you can inspect the contents of that array to see what is really in that first column.

As noted in the comments, a better approach would be to not blindly assume the parsing will succeed, and additionally you would probably want to ensure you're using the right cultural information.

Here's what I would do, assuming the numbers are output by a program, for reading into another program:

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(parts[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
    ... your code here, use value where you need it
else
    what to do in the case of unable to parse the string as a number
```

On a hunch, do you need to trim the contents? Try this simple change:

```
... int.Parse(line.Split(',')[0].Trim()) ...
                                ^--+--^
                                   |
                                   +-- add this
```

Other tips:

- Use `Path.Combine` to combine paths:

  ```
  new FileStream(Path.Combine(installPath, "storedUsers.txt")
  ```
- Rewrite your reading loop to this:

  ```
  string line;
  while ((line = userStream.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Use the `using` clause for disposing of your stream:

  ```
  using (FileStream userFile = new FileStream(...))
  {
      ...
  }
  // delete the .Close() line, this is handled by the } on the preceeding line
  ```

Final version:

```
installPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\";
using (FileStream userFile = new FileStream(
    Path.Combine(installPath, "storedUsers.txt"),
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
using (StreamReader userStream = new StreamReader(userFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = userStream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        int userId;
        if (Int32.TryParse(parts[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out userId))
            storedUsers.Add(userId);
    }
}
```

Of course, if the file isn't too big, you can rewrite the whole shebang using a bit of LINQ:

```
// warning, LINQ with side-effects, evaluate here, don't use it lazily
int tempUserId = 0;
List<int> userIds = File
    .ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(installPath, "storedUsers.txt"))
    .Select(l => l.Split(',')[0])
    .Where(p0 => Int32.TryParse(p0, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tempUserId))
    .Select(dummy => tempUserId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 - even though I would suggest using `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's better, I was aiming at adding a quick answer first, and then expanding it :)

Comment: haha... my fault was using the 0 index in the parse, it should have been [1] and works now since i know what im doing :P

Comment: and ty for putting me on the right direction about the exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with a checklist (or test cases), like:

1. Does the file exist? I am assuming here - yes.
2. Am I opening the file to read or write? If only read, then don't use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, but `FileMode.Open`.
3. What does `string line` contain?

   a) Is it blank?

4) What is the result of `Split` function call?

a) Is it null?

b) Are you accepting empty entries in this array?

c) Are there entries more than 0?

Then, avoid repeating code, if possible.

```
//Pseudo-code + C#
string line = userStream.ReadLine();
string[] arr = line.Split(','); //called once
if (arr.Length > 0 && arr[0].Trim().Length > 0) storedUsers.Add(arr[0], int.Parse(arr[0]));
//you can put extra checks.
```